# Navbar becomes fixed on scrolling in jquery 2.2.4 but not in jquery 3.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a website in `jekyll` using a predefined theme. However, in my `bower.json`, `jquery` version was mentioned as `"^3.1.0"`, the navbar is not fixed and moves up with scrolling down the page, whereas in the original source code, the version used was `2.2.3`, so when I changed my `jquery` version in `bower.json` to `"^2.2.3"`, it worked! This is the scrolling javascript code. Why is this happening? Also, is it recommended to update dependency versions in websites to the latest one, like should I update `jquery` to the latest?

```
// Window Scroll
var windowScroll = function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

        var system ={win : false,mac : false,xll : false};
        //¼ì²âÆ½Ì¨
        var p = navigator.platform;
        system.win = p.indexOf("Win") == 0;
        system.mac = p.indexOf("Mac") == 0;
        system.x11 = (p == "X11") || (p.indexOf("Linux") == 0);
        //ÅÐ¶ÏÆ½Ì¨ÀàÐÍ
        if(system.win||system.mac||system.xll){
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 70)
            {
                $('.site-header').addClass('site-header-nav-scrolled');
            } else {
                $('.site-header').removeClass('site-header-nav-scrolled');
            }
        }else{
            //Èç¹ûÊÇÊÖ»úÔò½«¶¥À¸ÒÆ³ý½çÃæ
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 40) 
            {
                $('.site-header').addClass('site-header-nav-scrolled-ph');
            } else {
                $('.site-header').removeClass('site-header-nav-scrolled-ph');
            }
        }
 });
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
    windowScroll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me at 3.1.1 https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/pujfta96/ .

Also, you create `scrollPos`, but use `$(window).scrollTop()` in your if-else statements.

You souldn't detect `system` for every scroll, just set it once out off `windowScroll`.